Google cloud build doesn't detect the variables passed in the pytest command but it works on local
I'm using pytest for my test execution, and I'm seeing a peculiar issue - when I run the tests locally, all the variables I pass in are sent to the test. When I run the same test on google cloud build, the same variables are printed as the $names of the variables instead. I see that I could be wrong about the way I'm currently using the scope for my fixtures but I am not able to pinpoint it. Can someone help me to figure out where am I making a mistake?
For example, here is the local test execution result:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- live log setup ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] my-user-id: valid_user_id (test_code.py:25)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] my-client-id: valid_client_id  (test_code.py:26)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] os.environ.my-user-id: valid_user_id (test_code.py:27)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] os.environ.my-client-id: valid_client_id  (test_code.py:28)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] request_params.MY_USER_ID: valid_user_id (test_code.py:29)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] request_params.MY_CLIENT_ID: valid_client_id (test_code.py:30)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] my-user-id: valid_user_id (test_code.py:50)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] my-client-id: valid_client_id  (test_code.py:51)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] my-user-id: valid_user_id (test_code.py:52)
May 16 2024 07:33PM [INFO] my-client-id: valid_client_id  (test_code.py:53)
PASSED

When I execute the same code via Google cloud build, this is what I see in the logs I've printed:
Step #1: ------------------------------ Captured log setup ------------------------------
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:25 my-user-id: $MY_USER_ID
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:26 my-client-id: $MY_CLIENT_ID 
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:27 my-user-id: $MY_USER_ID
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:28 my-client-id: $MY_CLIENT_ID 
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:29 MY_USER_ID: $MY_USER_ID
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:30 MY_CLIENT_ID: $MY_CLIENT_ID
Step #1: ------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:50 my-user-id: $MY_USER_ID
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:51 my-client-id: $MY_CLIENT_ID 
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:52 my-user-id: $MY_USER_ID
Step #1: INFO     test_code:test_code.py:53 my-client-id: $MY_CLIENT_ID
Step #1: =========================== short test summary info ============================

What I've tried so far :

Changing the scope for the set_env method from "session" to "module" makes it work. The code executes correctly on cloud build but  stops working when I test locally from my mac.
Changing the fixture scope to "function" breaks in both local and  cloud build.

I don't really understand why it behaves this way.
My goal is: If I am passing the same variables via pytest command in local or google cloud build, it should run in both places.
here's my setup:
  qa/
  |-- conftest.py
  |-- pytest.ini
  |-- build
     |-- cloudbuild.yaml
  |-- api
     |-- test_code.py


conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--my-client-id", action="store")
    parser.addoption("--my-user-id", action="store")
    parser.addoption("--my-tenant-id", action="store")
    parser.addoption("--version-name", action="store")

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def request_params(request):
    my_user_id = request.config.getoption("--my-user-id")
    my_tenant_id = request.config.getoption("--my-tenant-id")
    my_client_id = request.config.getoption("--my-client-id")
    version_name = request.config.getoption("--version-name")

    return params(my_user_id, my_tenant_id, my_client_id, version_name)

class params:
    def __init__(self, my_user_id, my_tenant_id, my_client_id, version_name):
        self.my_user_id = my_user_id
        self.my_tenant_id = my_tenant_id
        self.my_client_id = my_client_id
        self.version_name = version_name

test_code.py
import logging

import pytest
import requests
import os.path
import json
import time
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def setup_module(request_params):
    global my_user_id
    global my_tenant_id
    global my_session_id
    global my_client_id
    global my_base_url
    global version
    my_user_id = os.environ.get("MY_USER_ID", "not_found")
    my_client_id = os.environ.get("MY_CLIENT_ID", "not_found")
    my_tenant_id = os.environ.get("MY_TENANT_ID", "not_found")
    my_base_url = 'https://myapp.com/version/acc'

    LOGGER.info('my-user-id: %s' % my_user_id)
    LOGGER.info('my-client-id: %s ' % my_client_id)
    LOGGER.info('os.environ.my-user-id: %s' % os.environ.get("my_USER_ID", "not_found"))
    LOGGER.info('os.environ.my-client-id: %s ' % os.environ.get("my_CLIENT_ID", "not_found"))
    LOGGER.info('request_params.MY_USER_ID: %s' % str(request_params.my_user_id))
    LOGGER.info('request_params.MY_CLIENT_ID: %s' % str(request_params.my_client_id))

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def set_env(request_params):
    os.environ["MY_USER_ID"] = str(request_params.my_user_id)
    os.environ["MY_TENANT_ID"] = str(request_params.my_tenant_id)
    os.environ["MY_CLIENT_ID"] = str(request_params.my_client_id)
    os.environ["VERSION"] = str(request_params.version_name)

@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_audit(request_params):
    version = str(request_params.version_name)

    url = my_base_url + "/" + version + "/1.0/audit"

    headers = {
        'my-user-id': my_user_id,
        'my-client-id': my_client_id
    }

    LOGGER.info('my-user-id: %s' % my_user_id)
    LOGGER.info('my-client-id: %s ' % my_client_id)
    LOGGER.info('my-user-id: %s' % os.environ.get("MY_USER_ID", "not_found"))
    LOGGER.info('my-client-id: %s ' % os.environ.get("MY_CLIENT_ID", "not_found"))

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    assert r.status_code == 200

This is what my cloudbuild.yaml looks like:
steps:

# Smoke test
- name: 'python'
  entrypoint: 'pip'
  args: ['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt', '--user']
- name: 'python'
  entrypoint: 'python'
  args: [ '-m', 'pytest', '-m', 'smoke', '-v', '--my-user-id', '$$MY_USER_ID', '--my-tenant-id', '$$MY_TENANT_ID', '--my-client-id', '$$MY_CLIENT_ID', '--version-name', '${_VERSION}' ]
  secretEnv: ['MY_CLIENT_ID', 'MY_USER_ID', 'MY_TENANT_ID']
  env:
  - 'VERSION=${_VERSION}'

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/MY-client-id/versions/1
    env: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/MY-user-id/versions/1
    env: 'MY_USER_ID'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/MY-tenant-id/versions/1
    env: 'MY_TENANT_ID'

substitutions:
  _VERSION: "1"


